# How do you configure SSL with google app engine with a custom domain using letsencrypt (2016)

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, lets-encrypt

Using letsencrypt and gethttpsforfree, i've created the following files:

```
account.key <- private key
domain.crt
domain.key
intermediate.pem
```

When I log into the (new for 2016) GAE console, it has the following fields required:

[image]

For the private key, I use the account.key. However for the 'public key certificate' i'm not sure what i need to use, and I cannot figure out which combination of files i need.

Comment: The certificate is usually a concatenation of the certificate and all intermediates (**domain.crt** + **intermediate.pem**) . The key should be the key you generated (**account.key**). My guess is that **domain.key** is actually the certificate signing request and you don't need that one at all. Or: account.key is used for authentication with letsencrypt and the real key is the domain.key. Just try both, see what works.

Comment: I don't know how your filenames relate to the outputs of letsencrypt but I found [this guide](http://blog.seafuj.com/lets-encrypt-on-google-app-engine) very useful - you can do it all through the Cloud Shell.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where from you got this files, but for Let's Encrypt you'll get following in `live/www.yourdomain.com` directory:

```
cert.pem          
chain.pem 
fullchain.pem
privkey.pem
```

For *public key certificate* you should use `cert.pem`

And for *private key* you have to convert it first by using following command:

```
openssl rsa \
   -inform pem -in live/www.yourdomain.com/privkey.pem \
   -outform pem  > live/www.yourdomain.com/privkey_rsa.pem
```

The use resulting `privkey_rsa.pem` as a *RSA private key*

Answer (score 0):

I followed the guide here at tx802's suggestion and it succeeded:

http://blog.seafuj.com/lets-encrypt-on-google-app-engine

Comment: This is basically a link-only answer and should therefor rather be a comment. While the link may provide the answer today, there is no guarantee that the link won't break in the future. Please rewrite your answer so that it is meaningful without the link.